# Question with virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I have two classes:

```
class x {
public:
  virtual void hello() {
    std::cout << "x" << std::endl;
  }
};

class y : public x {
public:
  void hello() {
    std::cout << "y" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Can someone explain why the following two calls to hello() print different messages? Why don't they both print "y"? Is it because the first one is a copy while the second one actually points to the object in memory?

```
int main() {
  y  a;

  x b = a;
  b.hello(); // prints x

  x* c = &a;
  c->hello(); // prints y
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the first time I've seen someone correctly guess the cause, good job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you are right

```
x b = a;
```

Invokes a copy constructor (b IS an 'x')

```
x& b = a;
```

Assigns a reference and will use the override (b is still actually a 'y')

Answer (score 6):

Because `x b = a;` [slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) the object.

When this code executes, it creates a new `x`, not a `y`, which is a copy of the original `y`, `a`'.

Answer (score 0):

`x b = a` copies a to b. Since b is type x, you end up with an object of type x. An object of type x will print x.

The only way you get y is when you are calling into an object of type y.

Answer (score 0):

`b.hello()` prints "x" because `b` is an instance of class X.  `c->hello()` prints "y" because `c` points to `a`, and `a` is an instance of class Y.

What might be confusing for you is that when you write `x b = a;`, you're creating a new object `b` and initializing it with `a`.  When you write `x* c = &a;`, `c` is not a new object.  You just introduced an alias to an existing object.