# C++ real method overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading

I have the classes `A` and `B`. `B` derives from `A` and overloads the method `WhoAreYou()`, when I now create a variable of type `A` and set the value to a `B` object and then call `WhoAreYou()`, the method of `A` is called. Look at this:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void WhoAreYou(){
        cout << "I am A!"<<endl;
    }
};
class B: public A{
public:
    void WhoAreYou(){
        cout << "I am B!" << endl;
    }
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    A a = B();
    a.WhoAreYou(); //Output: I am A!
}
```

Is there a way to overload the method so, that in this case the `WhoAreYou()` method of B would be called? When I must cast the object first, a method overloading doesn´t really make sense in my opinion...

Thanky for your help!

Comment: That's overriding, not overloading.

Comment: `B` _overrides_ `WhoAreYou`.  Overloading would mean it also exists with a different set of arguments( e.g. `WhoAreYou(int)` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "a" variable is an A, not a B. `A a = B();` creates a new temporary B, then creates an A by copying the A part of B.

Try this:

```
B b;
A * a = &b;
a->WhoAreYou();
```

Comment: This works! Didn't know that there is a defference between pointers and normal objects in this case. Thanks!

Comment: Or use a reference: `A& a = b;`.

Comment: @FlashFan: Your variable "a" *is* an A. Nothing you do will change that, you declared it to be an A. Using references or pointers, you can refer to or point to something else, which is *at least* an A, as my sample shows.

Comment: Hey xtofl, I saw your answer and wanted to mark it as correct. But you deleted it...

Answer (score 1):

The problem has to do with **slicing**. I asked the *exact* same question with [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825685/question-with-virtual-functions).